# how to write this query in pl sql function , select * if(a=0) from table B else if (a=1) from table A else from table C

Tags: oracle

i use oracle databse and i want to select columns from table A or Table B or table C whith condition, so for example if i had a variable x,
if any one knew a solution or an idea please write it
i want to write a query:`select * if (x=0) from A else if(x=1) from B else from C`

I tried this but the compilation is failed

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION return_result (



l1 number,l2 number 
)
return object_table1 as
 v_ret   object_table1;
begin

  Select object1 (ax.column1,ax column2) BULK COLLECT INTO v_ret from (


select resultat.column1,resultat column2 from resultat
case when (l2-l1>1) then from(
select * from A) resultat
.
.
.


) ax;
  return v_ret;
end return_result;`
```

Comment: i found a solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming simple examples where TabA and TabB have the same structure, you can achieve the desired effect by eother:

```
IF l1 = 0 THEN
  SELECT *  BULK COLLECT INTO v_ret  FROM tabA;
END IF;
IF l1 = 1 THEN
  SELECT *  BULK COLLECT INTO v_ret  FROM tabB;
END IF;
```

Or

```
WITH A AS ( SELECT * FROM tabA WHERE l1 = 0 ),
B AS ( SELECT * FROM tabA WHERE l1 = 1 )
SELECT * FROM A
UNION
SELECT * FROM B;
```